# ISupportIncrementalLoading combined with VariableSizedWrapGrid

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, lazy-loading

I have an `ObservableCollection<T>` which implements the `ISupportIncrementalLoading` interface.

When I bind this collection to a normal gridview, everything works fine.

But when I change the ItemsPanel template, to VariableSizedWrapGrid. The incremental loading doesn't work any more.

Xaml that works:

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate>                        
    <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

Xaml that doesn't work:

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Vertical" ItemHeight="250" ItemWidth="250"  Margin="0,0,80,0"/>
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

I've also found [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/11cb4e1a-302b-4306-9426-e350eb335931) & [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/605467fb-0a20-4da7-a0bf-30a9f9d6e62c). Stating the `VariableSizedWrapGrid` doesn't support `ISupportIncremetalLoading`.

Is there anyone that have written a VariableSizedWrapGrid, that supports Incremental loading? Or an opensource solution?

Answer (score 0):

There are only two panels that support the incremental loading: VirtualizingStackPanel and WrapGrid. I do not know about any open-source solution.

Answer (score 0):

It does not support because the panel itself has to be able to virtualize elements. Since the datatemplates insice a VariableSizedWrapGrid are different, is not possible to virtualize, so every element you want to draw has to be present at the begining.